# Airflow SSHOperator: How To Securely Access Pem File Across Tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

We are running Airflow via AWS's managed MWAA Offering.  As part of their offering they [include a tutorial on securely using the SSH Operator in conjunction with AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-ssh.html).  The gist of how their solution works is described below:

1. Run a Task that fetches the pem file from a Secrets Manager location and store it on the filesystem at /tmp/mypem.pem.
2. In the SSH Connection include the extra information that specifies the file location

```
{"key_file":"/tmp/mypem.pem"}
```

3. Use the SSH Connection in the SSHOperator.

In short the workflow is supposed to be:

`Task1 gets the pem -> Task2 uses the pem via the SSHOperator`

All of this is great in theory, but it doesn't actually work.  It doesn't work because Task1 may run on a different node from Task2, which means Task2 can't access the /tmp/mypem.pem file location that Task1 wrote the file to.  AWS is aware of this limitation according to AWS Support, but now we need to understand another way to do this.

***Question***

How can we securely store and access a pem file that can then be used by Tasks running on different nodes via the SSHOperator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by holly is good.  I am sharing a different way I solved this problem.  I used the strategy of converting the SSH Connection into a URI and then input that into Secrets Manager under the expected connections path, and everything worked great via the SSH Operator.  Below are the general steps I took.

1. Generate an encoded URI

```
import json
from airflow.models.connection import Connection
from pathlib import Path

pem = Path(“/my/pem/file”/pem).read_text()

myconn= Connection(
    conn_id="connX”,
    conn_type="ssh",
    host="10.x.y.z,
    login=“mylogin”,
    extra=json.dumps(dict(private_key=pem)),

print(myconn.get_uri())
```

2. Input that URI under the environment's configured path in Secrets Manager.  **The important note here is to input the value in the plaintext field without including a key**.  Example:

`airflow/connections/connX` and under Plaintext only include the URI value

3. Now in the SSHOperator you can reference this connection Id like any other.

```
remote_task = SSHOperator(
        task_id="ssh_and_execute_command",
        ssh_conn_id="connX"
        command="whoami",
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I extended the SSHOperator to do both steps in one call.

In AWS Secrets Manager, two keys are added for airflow to retrieve on execution.

```
{variables_prefix}/airflow-user-ssh-key : the value of the private key
{connections_prefix}/ssh_airflow_user : ssh://replace.user@replace.remote.host?key_file=%2Ftmp%2Fairflow-user-ssh-key
```

```
from typing import Optional, Sequence
from os.path import basename, splitext

from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh import SSHHook


class SSHOperator(SSHOperator):
    """
    SSHOperator to execute commands on given remote host using the ssh_hook.
    :param ssh_conn_id: :ref:`ssh connection id<howto/connection:ssh>`
        from airflow Connections.
    :param ssh_key_var: name of Variable holding private key.
        Creates "/tmp/{variable_name}.pem" to use in SSH connection.
        May also be inferred from "key_file" in "extras" in "ssh_conn_id".
    :param remote_host: remote host to connect (templated)
        Nullable. If provided, it will replace the `remote_host` which was
        defined in `ssh_hook` or predefined in the connection of `ssh_conn_id`.
    :param command: command to execute on remote host. (templated)
    :param timeout: (deprecated) timeout (in seconds) for executing the command. The default is 10 seconds.
        Use conn_timeout and cmd_timeout parameters instead.
    :param environment: a dict of shell environment variables. Note that the
        server will reject them silently if `AcceptEnv` is not set in SSH config.
    :param get_pty: request a pseudo-terminal from the server. Set to ``True``
        to have the remote process killed upon task timeout.
        The default is ``False`` but note that `get_pty` is forced to ``True``
        when the `command` starts with ``sudo``.
    """

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("command", "remote_host")
    template_ext: Sequence[str] = (".sh",)
    template_fields_renderers = {"command": "bash"}

    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        ssh_conn_id: Optional[str] = None,
        ssh_key_var: Optional[str] = None,
        remote_host: Optional[str] = None,
        command: Optional[str] = None,
        timeout: Optional[int] = None,
        environment: Optional[dict] = None,
        get_pty: bool = False,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            ssh_conn_id=ssh_conn_id,
            remote_host=remote_host,
            command=command,
            timeout=timeout,
            environment=environment,
            get_pty=get_pty,
            **kwargs,
        )

        if ssh_key_var is None:
            key_file = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=self.ssh_conn_id).key_file
            key_filename = basename(key_file)
            key_filename_no_extension = splitext(key_filename)[0]
            self.ssh_key_var = key_filename_no_extension
        else:
            self.ssh_key_var = ssh_key_var

    def import_ssh_key(self):
        with open(f"/tmp/{self.ssh_key_var}", "w") as file:
            file.write(Variable.get(self.ssh_key_var))

    def execute(self, context):
        self.import_ssh_key()
        super().execute(context)
```